# How to get the (real) current date, in React Native whilst a User is offline

Tags: date, react-native

I am building an offline-first application which determines a User's membership status based on date.

```
Todays Date: 18th September 2018
Membership End Date: 10th August 2018 <-- Expired
```

However, using `new Date()` returns the system date (checked via an Expo snack). The problem with this is that a User can go into their Settings and modify the date.

```
Todays Date: 18th September 2018
Membership End Date: 10th August 2018 <-- Expired
System Date: 09th August 2018
```

What are some of the ways which we can prevent this? I suspect using anything native will also use the System date.

Answer (score 2):

The Membership status details should be computed in the **server** and not in the **client**.

This would help to *check the date based on the timezone the server is hoisted* and avoid additional checks in all the client devices.

Once the application is synced to the server it will fetch the required **Membership details** along with its `status` and `end date`.

If you want to update the status of the **Membership** realtime and not rely on device time, then you also need to

- Fetch `current date` from the server
- Run a background task to update `date timer`.
- Check the date timer with the `Membership End Date`

Comment: I totally agree with this concept, there is concern around offline usage. What happens if a User (with a valid membership) starts using the app, then once their membership expires they disable their connection on each subsequent use?

Comment: The workflow is similar to all the applications that we use. Taking the reference of some softwares such as `Sketch Tools` and `Adobe Products`, you can continue to use them offline if the membership has expired. But once they are synced to the server(online) and status is checked then the user is logged out and needs to purchase a new license

Comment: But if you want a stricter validation, then follow the second part of my answer and track time in your app manually with capability to sync with server sent time.